# git-svn rename tracking branch

Tags: git, git-svn

My current svn cloned branches (using the -s 'standard layout') option are called:

```
$ git branch -r
branch1
branch2
```

I would like to rename those, such that they are:

```
$ git branch -r
svn/branch1
svn/branch2
```

As though I had called $ git-svn clone --prefix svn   originally.  I don't need to change any names on the remote side.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming that you do not have another remote that was added with `git remote add ...`, try this procedure:

1. `git gc` to package all refs into `.git/packed-refs`.
2. Open `.git/packed-refs` for editing. Replace "refs/remotes/" with "refs/remotes/svn/".
3. Open `.git/config` for editing. You should see something like:

   ```
   [svn-remote "svn"]
       url = SVN_REPO_URL
       fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
       branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
       tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
   ```

   Replace "refs/remotes/" with "refs/remotes/svn/":

   ```
   [svn-remote "svn"]
       url = SVN_REPO_URL
       fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
       branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/svn/*
       tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*
   ```

   Be sure to also update any remote-tracking branches. To do this, you can just replace "refs/remotes/" with "refs/remotes/svn/" in the entire file.

I tested this procedure with a copy of my git-svn mirror of the GNU Nano repository and it seems to work.

**EDIT:** I have just verified that this procedure does not mess up the git-svn dcommit or rebase operations. It is as if `--prefix=svn/` were originally specified in the `git svn clone -s SVN_REPO_URL` command.

Comment: Thank you, this is comprehensive!

Comment: I also had to move `.git/svn/refs/remotes/trunk` to `.git/svn/refs/remotes/svn/trunk` - without, I got a `open: No such file or directory at C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 561` error when doing `git svn fetch`.

Comment: With newer versions of git-svn, the default prefix is "origin/" if unspecified in the init or clone commands. I also noticed there are references to "refs/remotes/origin" in .git/info/refs as well. Presumably these also need to be renamed to "refs/remotes/svn"?