# How can I change the Prefix Mapping in a Git-Svn Repository?

Tags: git-svn, prefix

I've created a Git Clone of a SVN repository using git-svn. When doing this I specified the `--prefix` option to prefix my remote branches. I now want to get rid of this prefix.

Is there a way to update or remove the prefix without re-cloning the repository?

Essentially I did the initial clone using `--prefix=Project` so I ended up with `Project/trunk`  and `Project/feature-branch` as my remote tracking branches. What I want is to have the `trunk` just be called `trunk` and the `feature-branch` be called `svn/feature-branch`.

Comment: There is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4381814/421146) question which is answered.

Comment: Warning: with git 2.0+ (April 2014), having just '`trunk`' (without prefix) might not work anymore. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24714294/6309)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: the current solution might not work anymore with git 2.0+ (April 2014)

See [commit fe191fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe191fcaa58cb785c804465a0da9bcba9fd9e822) by [Johan Herland  (`jherland`](https://github.com/jherland)), which highlight the fact you now are *supposed* to have a prefix (and *not* have a svn branch *without* prefix like '`trunk`'):

#### Git 2.0: [`git svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn): Set default `--prefix='origin/'` if `--prefix` is not given

Having no prefix by default was problematic:

> `git-svn` by default puts its Subversion-tracking refs directly in `refs/remotes/*`.
>   This runs counter to Git's convention of using **`refs/remotes/$remote/*`** for storing remote-tracking branches.
>
> Furthermore, combining `git-svn` with regular git remotes run the risk of clobbering refs under refs/remotes (e.g. if you have a `git remote` called "`tags`" with a "`v1`" branch, it will overlap with the git-svn's tracking branch for the "`v1`" tag from Subversion.

Answer (score 9):

I've done the following which appears to have worked.

In `.git/config` I updated the fetch, branches and tags settings to update the local refs. It was:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = http://subversion/......
        fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/Project/trunk
        branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/Project/*
        tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/Project/tags/*
```

Which I changed to

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = http://subversion/......
        fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
        branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/svn/*
        tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*
```

The within `.git/refs/remotes` I moved trunk out of the `Project` folder and the remaining refs within `Project` into a new folder called `svn`. The structure was:

- remotes

  - Project

    - trunk
    - feature-branch

Which I changed to:

- remotes

  - trunk
  - svn

    - feature-branch

I also performed the same restructuring of folders within `.git/svn/refs/remotes/`.

Finally I triggered a `git svn fetch`. I had to specify the -r argument to limit to the same start revision that I used for my initial clone, but it doesn't appear to have re-fetched the old revisions.