# git-svn workflow for merging using svn.pushmergeinfo

Tags: git, svn, merge, git-svn, mergeinfo

What is the correct workflow for merging svn tracked branches using git-svn. I've read a little about the git-svn svn.pushmergeinfo config key, and the caveats are:

From http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html:

> config key: svn.pushmergeinfo
>
> This option will cause git-svn to
>   attempt to automatically populate the svn:mergeinfo property in the
>   SVN repository when possible. Currently, this can only be done when
>   dcommitting non-fast-forward merges where all parents but the first
>   have already been pushed into SVN.

So my normal workflow is:

Assuming I have an SVN branch ^/branches/feature_branch

```
# Ensure git-svn is configured to populate svn:mergeinfo
git config --global svn.pushmergeinfo true   

# Update my local svn remotes state
git svn fetch

# Track a local branch against a remote SVN backed ^/branches/feature_branch 
git checkout -b local_feature_branch remotes/feature_branch

# Modify files and commit to local git repo
git commit -a -m "changes"
# Push changes to SVN branch ^/branches/feature_branch
git svn dcommit
```

Then to merge up ^/trunk into my local_feature_branch I assume I do something like?

```
# Sync to the latest SVN
git svn fetch
# Rebase "master" which is tracking the remote SVN ^/trunk
git checkout master
git svn rebase

# Checkout the local_feature_branch
git checkout local_feature_branch

# Merge "master" into "local_feature" which is tracking ^/trunk
git merge --squash master
git commit -m "merge master which is tracking SVN ^/trunk"

# Dry run the dcommit to SVN which should include svn:mergeinfo property changes
git svn dcommit --dry-run

# Commit merge to trunk
git svn dcommit
```

Comment: Looks reasonable. What's the question about?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using *merge --squash* and *svn.pushmergeinfo* together doesn't make much sense. With merge --squash, the resulting commit won't be a merge commit, so a subsequent *dcommit* won't create any mergeinfo.

I know that (mostly older) threads here on stackoverflow suggest using --squash, but I think that's largely a relic of the past. I have been using git-svn to manage our company's svn repos for close to a year now, and so far it worked great with the following workflow:

I always make sure before a merge that I am up-to-date and, just to be safe, that I don't have any local unsynced commits:

```
# On local_feature_branch
# Update from SVN
git svn fetch && git svn rebase -l

# push pending commits
git svn dcommit
```

Then I do a 'real' merge, using the "remote" SVN branch as source. This saves switching branches and updating, and ensures that the incoming branch doesn't have any local unsynced commits:

```
# Create a real, non-forward merge commit
git merge --no-ff svn/trunk

# ... and push it to SVN, including mergeinfo
git svn dcommit
```

Also, this way the merge gets properly recorded in the local history, so subsequent merges won't have to deal with previously resolved conflicts. With --squash you'd reencounter those with every merge.

Note however that there is an open issue with mergeinfo when merging back from local_feature_branch to trunk (i.e. a reintegrate in svn-speak): [Git-SVN with svn.pushmergeinfo: how to avoid self-referencing mergeinfo lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700998/git-svn-with-svn-pushmergeinfo-how-to-avoid-self-referencing-mergeinfo-lines). This has happened rarely in our repo, but so far it didn't cause any trouble for me.

Comment: Do you have any details on avoiding the self-referential mergeinfo when merging the feature branch down to trunk?

Comment: No, so far I just ignored the issue without any problem. Not sure if some svn clients might have an issue with it, but so far we didn't experience any problems with git-svn, command-line svn or Eclipse Subversive (and I think Tortoise SVN, too)

Comment: **EDIT** Re-reading the detailed description at [link](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/191932), this probably never hit us because we've done all the (rare) reintegration merges that happened in that time with git.

Comment: I don't have an `svn/trunk` has git-svn changed how it names remote branches? Would it be `remotes/trunk` now?

Comment: @Sam short answer: Yes, it's remotes/trunk by default. Long-ish answer: git-svn will by default put all your "remote" svn branches directly under remotes/. In order to get a more familiar git-remote-like layout, I always use --prefix=svn/ with git svn clone/git svn init, which gives me remotes/svn/trunk etc. That's where my svn/trunk is coming from...

Comment: Now I wish I'd done that when I cloned. Presumably I can do the reverse of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986379/how-can-i-change-the-prefix-mapping-in-a-git-svn-repository to add the prefix. Although I'm not sure if that's a good idea according to this: http://blog.tfnico.com/2013/08/always-use-git-svn-with-prefix.html